# MVC 5 use session to store login information?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, authentication

This is more a question regarding a proper approach than a coding issue. Let's say I have an MVC application with a registration and login system. I have a SQL database where I store the registration information and connect to it when the user wants to log in.

Once I authenticate the user, is it ok to store the information required ( like username ) into a session variable and then reference that throughout the application?

Comment: Yes. Although you might want to look into the SQL-based membership provider as it handles all of this for you.

Comment: What are your concerns with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but not recommended due to many reasons.
Use [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) to do all that. Latest versions of Visual Studio come with great sample MVC projects that implement full registration / login / lost password etc. loop.

Comment: I'm aware of Identity but to my knowing, that requires Entity Framework. The reason for my question, I should have said, is that I am trying to have a system WITHOUT using EF. Or is there a way to use Identity without EF?

Comment: You can plug your own storage, absolutely. Have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity).